# Separating text in r

Tags: r, dataframe, feature-engineering

I have a data.frame that contains a column named movies_name. this column contain data as in this format: **City of Lost Children, The (Cité des enfants perdus, La) (1995)** I want to separate the year from the rest of the movie name without losing the text inside the brackets. to be more precise I want to create a new column holding the year and another one for the movie name alone.

I tried this approach but now I cannot gather back the movie name:

[My approach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bk19g.png)

thanks

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please [do not post code or data in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2372064)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the function `extract` from `tidyr`(part of the `tidyverse`):

```
library(tidyverse)    
df %>%
  extract(movies_name,
          into = c("title", "year"), 
          regex = "(\\D+)\\s\\((\\d+)\\)")
                                                         title year
    1 City of Lost Children, The (Cité des enfants perdus, La) 1995
    2                                             another film 2020
```

How the regex works:

- `(\\D+)`: first capture group, matching one or more characters that are **not** digits
- `\\s\\(`: a whitespace and an opening parenthesis (not captured)
- `(\\d+)`: second capture group, matching one or more `dìgits
- `\\)`: closing bracket (not captured)

Data 1:

```
df <- data.frame(
  movies_name = c("City of Lost Children, The (Cité des enfants perdus, La) (1995)",
                  "another film (2020)")
)
```

**EDIT**:

Okay, following comment, let's make this a little more complex by including a title with digits (in the title!):

Data 2:

```
df <- data.frame(
  movies_name = c("City of Lost Children, The (Cité des enfants perdus, La) (1995)",
                  "another film (2020)",
                  "Under Siege 2: Dark Territory (1995)")
)
```

Solution - actually easier than the previous one ;)

```
df %>%
  extract(movies_name,
          into = c("title", "year"), 
          regex = "(.+)\\s\\((\\d+)\\)")
                                                     title year
1 City of Lost Children, The (Cité des enfants perdus, La) 1995
2                                             another film 2020
3                            Under Siege 2: Dark Territory 1995
```

Comment: If it helped why not accept and/or upvote?

Comment: +1 for extract, though digits in titles are pretty common (MoviLens dataset for reference - https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/grouplens/movielens-20m-dataset?select=movie.csv )

Comment: unfortnately, I am not eligable to upvote (need more than 15 reputation to upvote).

Answer (score 0):

This looks for a number in round brackets at the end of the string, using `stringr`.

```
data.frame(movies, year = stringr::str_match(movies$movie, "\\((\\d+)\\)$")[,2])
                                                                   movie year
1 City of Lost Children, The (Cité des enfants (2002) perdus, La) (1995) 1995
2        City of Lost Children, The (Cité des enfants perdus, La) (1995) 1995
```

##### Data

```
movies <- structure(list(movie = c("City of Lost Children, The (Cité des enfants (2002) perdus, La) (1995)",
"City of Lost Children, The (Cité des enfants perdus, La) (1995)"
)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```